# How to do a random sleep in AHK?

Tags: vba

I'm running AHK with VBA macro and I'm trying to pull out some data from a website. But when I reload the website 20 times, It's thinking that I'm a robot.

My plan is to do a random sleep in AHK when I reload the webpage so that it won't know that I'm running a program.

**Is there a way to do solve this? How can I do a random sleep in AutoHotKeys?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AHK
[Sleep](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Sleep.htm)

```
Sleep, DelayInMilliseconds
```

Example

```
Sleep, 1000  ; 1 second
```

[Random](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/Random.htm)

```
Random, OutputVar [, Min, Max]
Random, , NewSeed
```

Example

```
Random, rand, 1, 10
Random, rand, 0.0, 1.0
```

---

VBA

**Excel**

```
Application.Wait(Time)
```

**Access**

```
Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" Alias "Sleep" _
(ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
```

Now you can call it

```
Sub Sleep()
    Sleep 1000 '1 sec
End Sub
```

Rnd function

[Rnd()](http://www.599cd.com/glossary/access/math/rnd/)

Comment: Awesome. Thanks @alexHedley.